# Displacing a 2D procreate painting to simulate thickness of paint

Tags: texturing, texture-painting, displacement

I am interested in creating a believable "[Impasto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impasto#:%7E:text=Impasto)" effect of paint. I am a 2D artist who uses Procreate. I've tried Art Set 4 and a couple other ipad programs but did not like them.

I was able to import my image as plane in Blender and paint a displacement map in Procreate and apply it in the Blender shader. I was able to do ok, but I am after this effect in particular:

[image]

The above image was with a displacement map generated in Verve painter for Windows and applied in Blender. I would like to keep to Procreate, and I don't have a windows computer but a Mac and just an iPad. Any displacement map generation techniques would be greatly appreciated!

My full question is:
**How can I use blender to create a thick paint effect on top of my 2D painting process?**

Is there a way to paint impasto easily in Blender or generate it? My displacement map generation process is hazy right now and could use some help because it does not look like the image linked above. Any other software suggestions are welcome too.

The Procreate forums discussion featuring some of my attempts.
https://folio.procreate.art/discussions/3/6/39383

This is the shader I used on my image plane:
http://www.reynantemartinez.com/how-to-generate-texture-maps-from-a-single-image.html

Thanks,
Arjun.

Comment: Hello :). Forgive my lack of knowledge, but how is such Displacement map different from a regular black and white image [like this](https://oneofakindmosaics.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/large-white-painting-abstract-textured-wall-art-urban-original-impasto-painting-on-stretched-canvas-stylish-design-30x30-custom-57fe780c2.jpg)?

Comment: Yes it is similar. A black and white image, but I tried various values of black and white and could not end up at a result like the one shown in the reference. Unfortunately I don't know what the displacement map of that image in particular is like.